# Why is aggdraw image blank?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, aggdraw

I am trying to draw a bunch of line segments using Pillow and aggdraw. With just pillow, my code was working - but I needed much smoother lines. I can't seem to get any lines drawn with aggdraw.

```
import aggdraw
from PIL import Image

image = Image.new("RGB", (ROW_SIZE, COL_SIZE), (255,255,255))
#draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw = aggdraw.Draw(image)
pen = aggdraw.Pen("black", 2)

# Each segment contains two points with x and y coordinates
for segment in segments:
   draw.line((segment.point1.x, segment.point1.y, segment.point2.x, segment.point2.y), pen)

image.show()
```

I also tried changing the import to `from aggdraw import Draw, Pen` and changing the usage accordingly - to no avail.

Comment: Try adding `draw.flush()` just above `image.show()`

Comment: Ah, so simple. Thank you!

Comment: I've put it as an answer as it appears to work for you. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
...
for segment in segments:
    draw.line((segment.point1.x, segment.point1.y, segment.point2.x, segment.point2.y), pen)

# Add the following line
draw.flush()
image.show()
```